# How to install unattended-upgrades on Debian Buster docker container?

Tags: linux, docker, debian, apt

I'm building a docker image based on Debian Buster, and I now want to use [unattended-upgrades](https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades) within the container.

Unfortunately, the package doesn't seem to be available:

```
root@0c5100b570a8:/# apt install unattended-upgrades
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package unattended-upgrades
```

Does anybody know how I can install the `unattended-upgrades` package in the Debian Buster container?

Comment: Can you share your `Dockerfile`?

Answer (score 2):

you need to update first:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y unattended-upgrades
```

Comment: @funnydman is re-producable, it wont work without update , try with `docker run -ti debian:buster bash`